# Error en el return de 2 variables - cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola soy nuevo en python y estaba practicando haciendo una especie "Tres en línea". Sin embargo en la función para obtener el ganador quiero devolver 2 valores, el True para que mi while termine y el True para mi bool e indicar que yo soy el ganador.

```
def ganarJuego(board):

if board['top-L'] == 'X' and board['top-M']  == 'X' and board['top-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['mid-L'] == 'X' and board['mid-M'] == 'X' and board['mid-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['low-L'] == 'X' and board['low-M'] == 'X' and  board['low-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['top-L'] == 'X' and board['mid-L'] == 'X' and  board['low-L'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['top-M'] == 'X' and board['mid-M'] == 'X' and  board['low-M'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['top-R'] == 'X' and board['mid-R'] == 'X' and  board['low-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['top-L'] == 'X' and board['mid-M'] == 'X' and  board['low-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
elif board['low-L'] == 'X' and board['mid-R'] == 'X' and  board['top-R'] == 'X':
    return True, True
```

En esta parte del codigo evalúo si se ha ganado pero cuando llamo a la siguiente función obtengo un error:

```
def main():

final = False
valor = False
yaSalieron = []
posicion = 0
print('Hola quieres jugar?')

while final != True:
    printBoard(theBoard)
    ingresoTeclaP(theBoard,yaSalieron)
    (final, valor) = ganarJuego(theBoard) #Aqui es donde obtengo el error

    ingresoTeclaB(theBoard,yaSalieron)
    final = ganarJuegoB(theBoard)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es porque cuando no se cumple ninguna condición en la función, esta no tiene nada que retornar (porque no tiene `else` o condición inicial) así que retornará `None`. Cuando trata de desempacar `None` para asignarselo a `final` y `valor`, obtienes el error que pusiste en el título.

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste agregar el else al final del ganarJuego para que el while continue?

```
...
else:
    return False, False
```

Esto va a hacer que el while continue y le va a pedir al usuario que ingrese otra opción.

Suerte.